# Java implicit try-with-resources

Tags: java, try-with-resources

I am wondering if the following code uses the try-with-resources correctly.

```
try (ResultSet rs = new QueryBuilder(connection, tableName(), getPaths(), searchQuery()).add(constraint).build().executeQuery()) {
    while (rs.next()) {
        beans.add(createBean(rs));
    }
}
```

The arguments are not important, the only important thing is:

- `new QueryBuilder().build();` returns a `PreparedStatement`.

I completely understand that `rs` will be closed, but will the `PreparedStatement` also be closed, and if so, for what reason? Because the `ResultSet` closes or because of the try-with-resources?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[PreparedStatement#close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close()) will automatically close any associated result sets but the reverse is not true because statements are reusable after their result sets are closed.

Look at the javadoc of [ResultSet#close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#close()):

> **Note:** A ResultSet object is automatically closed by the Statement object that generated it when that Statement object is closed

And then [Statement#close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close()):

> **Note:** When a Statement object is closed, its current ResultSet object, if one exists, is also closed.

This usage looks very crappy to me :

```
ResultSet rs=conn.createStatement().executeQuery();
```

If executed enough times it will leak all of the available cursors, because cursors are associated with the `Statement` not with `ResultSet`.

Hence to close the underlying `PreparedStatement` with [try-with-resources statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3) , just declare it within the `try` statement :

> A try-with-resources statement is **parameterized with variables (known as resources)** that are initialized before execution of the try block and **closed automatically**.

Look at [this answer from assylias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17788409/1163607), declare the `PreparedStatement` as well as `ResultSet` inside the `try` statement.

Since you are not looking for a **memory leak, but a resource leak** . The memory of the `PreparedStatement` will be collected eventually and it's memory freed, as it is not referenced anymore after execution of your method given the way it is initialized , however, the resources hold by the `Statement` is not closed .

Answer (score 9):

You can include several resources in the try, and they will all be closed - which is necessary if you want the `PreparedStatement` to be closed:

```
try (PreparedStatement ps = new QueryBuilder(connection, tableName(), getPaths(), searchQuery()).add(constraint).build();
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();) {
    while (rs.next()) {
        beans.add(createBean(rs));
    }
}
```

Comment: I've had that (and will have again now), but I was kind of trying to avoid two different declarations.

Comment: @skiwi I actually find splitting it in two statements more readable, not less.

Comment: Do you actually need to declare the ResultSet in the try-with-resources?  Can't it be safely declared in the body of the try block and automatically closed by the PreparedStatement when it is closed?  Not trying to nit-pick your code, I'm just not sure if that's how it'll work or not.

Comment: @GregH I'm never 100% sure of what happens to the ResultSet when the Statement is closed and I think I've read that some drivers do not release resources as you would expect. It doesn't cost anything to also close the ResultSet so I just do it. But you are right that it should be safe to place `ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()` in the body of the try block because it should get closed when you close the PreparedStatement.

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation [here - tryResourceClose](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), as I read it, it is specific to resources that are `declared`.

`The try-with-resources statement is a try statement that declares one or more resources.`

Reading further down you see:

`You may declare one or more resources in a try-with-resources statement. The following example retrieves the names of the files packaged in the zip file zipFileName and creates a text file that contains the names of these files:`

```
 try (
      java.util.zip.ZipFile zf =
         new java.util.zip.ZipFile(zipFileName);
    java.io.BufferedWriter writer = 
        java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedWriter(outputFilePath, charset)
  ) {
```

I suggest the correct answer to you issue is the following:

```
try{
  PreparedStatement statement = new QueryBuilder(connection, tableName(), getPaths(), searchQuery())
       .add(constraint).build();
  ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery()) 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As you correctly stated, `rs` will be closed. This means actually that the `close()` method will be invoked on `rs`. So the try-with-ressource statement doesn't explictly close the `PreparedStatement` in your case.

If it's closed otherwise (in context of the `rs.close()`) is kind of hard to say without knowing the implementation ;-)

**EDIT**

As @TheNewIdiot correctly found out, your `PreparedStatement` won't be closed.